# in blender 3.6 rigify basic_spine rigtype, how to change b-bone segment numbers on generated rig

Tags: rigify

I found super_spine type is deprecated, the default meta-rig is using basic_spine type,

however, after generating  the rig, I found the spine deformation bones are with bendy bone segments, but I found the number of segments is fixed when generating.

is there a way to change the segments on metarig and generate accordingly results on final rig?

I tried changing b_bone segments numbers on metarig under both pose mode and edit mode, but it did not work. I dont want to manually change the segments on final rig every time after adjusting the meta_rig and regenerate.